# tcpdump filter for post request and specific url path

Tags: url, post, filter, tcpdump

I had a doubt about a tcpdump capture.

I have to capture all post request on the sniffed host, and I know how to do this; I found here and on other site how to capture, for example, all post request on a web server with filter like:

```
tcpdump -i enp0s8 -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x504F5354'
```

But I wonder: it is possible to capture only the request for specific path exposed on server?

For example, suppose that I have the `www.site.com` and on this site I have the following path:

```
www.site.com/test/folder
www.site.com/update/download
```

is it possible to create a tcpdump filter to capture only post request for `/test/folder` and `/update/download` path?